# Why does a target attribute set to "_top" or "_parent" opens up in a new tab

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs, target

I've set the following links (found on DEMO) to open in the same tab by using the "_top" target (tried "_parent" as well, but for some reason they keep opening in a new tab. I've tried different browsers, and different devices but it still happens.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // for slide-out menu
  $('.js-nav').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.menu').toggleClass('active');
    if ($(this).find('i.fa').hasClass('fa-bars')) {
      $(this).find('i.fa').removeClass('fa-bars').addClass('fa-times');
    } else if ($(this).find('i.fa').hasClass('fa-times')) {
      $(this).find('i.fa').removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-bars');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
}
.toggle-nav {
  margin: auto 0 auto 0;
  float: left;
  color: #423c4c;
}
.toggle-nav:hover {
  color: #423c4c;
}
.nav-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.menu {
  float: left;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  right: 100%;
  transition-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 5s;
}
.menu.active {
  visibility: visible;
  right: 0px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
}
.menu ul {
  text-align: justify;
  min-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.menu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu ul li {
  margin-top: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Alef', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #423c4c;
}
.menu ul li a:link {
  color: #423c4c;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul li a:visited {
  color: #423c4c;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
  <!-- border-bottom: 1px solid #423c4c;
  -->text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fce2e2;
  ;
  color: red;
}
.menu ul li a:active {
  color: #423c4c;
}
.menu ul li ul {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 272px;
  top: 25px;
}
.menu ul li ul li {
  display: table;
  font-size: 13px;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #fce2e2;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  min-width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="toggle-nav js-nav" href="#/"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></a>
<div class="nav-wrap">
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="http://google.com" target="_top">link1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://pinterest.com" target="_top">link2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.awwwards.com" target="_top">link3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://dribbble.com" target="_top">link4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1bjna07p/)

Please help.

Thanks

Mey

Comment: Are you using `iframe`?

Comment: We use target `_top` for iframe, If you are usign iframe and want all click open in parent tab then you can use `_top` otherwise no need to use it.

Comment: common question....what is the question? I don't find any.....!!

Comment: did you try removing `target`? default is to open in same tab when link is in main page and not in a frame

Comment: Are you testing this at fiddle? ... If you create a html file on your local computer this work fine

Comment: Note it does no good to try and modify the links after they are clicked if they are opening new page

Comment: LGSon, I did test it...I added a JSFiddle link below my question.

Comment: Jai, I wasn't able to find any answer for this question...

Comment: @mey You cannot test tab handling in jsFiddle. Their iFrame handling blocks all sorts of stuff have a look here: http://plungjan.name/SO/tabtest.html - your code works

Comment: Hi @mplugjan, thank you, though it still doesn't work on my end. here is a link to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bidokeyiqa/edit?html,output). It still opens up in a new tab....

Comment: JSBin has the same issue as JSFiddle. Does it open in a new tab when you use my site? Also if you click the arrow to go full screen, JSBin also opens in the same tab

Comment: @mplungjan thank you! I tried going full screen and it worked...do you have any idea why? right now it appears so random to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem stems from the presence of the sandbox attribute on the iFrame used by JSFiddle and other such sites including StackOverflow's StackSnippets.

Your code works when stand alone like [here](http://plungjan.name/SO/tabtest.html)

By having the attribute set but **NOT** having the *allow-top-navigation* set, it is not allowed to break out of the frame except to a new window/tab

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

> **sandbox HTML5 only**
>
> If specified as an empty string, this attribute enables extra restrictions on the content that can appear in the inline frame. The value of the attribute can either be an empty string (all the restrictions are applied), or a space-separated list of tokens that lift particular restrictions. Valid tokens are:
>
> - allow-forms: Allows the embedded browsing context to submit forms. If this keyword is not used, this operation is not allowed.
> - allow-modals: Allows the embedded browsing context to open modal windows.
> - allow-orientation-lock: Allows the embedded browsing context to disable the ability to lock the screen orientation.
> - allow-pointer-lock: Allows the embedded browsing context to use the Pointer Lock API.
> - allow-popups: Allows popups (like from window.open, target="_blank", showModalDialog). If this keyword is not used, that functionality will silently fail.
> - allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox:  Allows a sandboxed document to open new windows without forcing the sandboxing flags upon them. This will allow, for example, a third-party advertisement to be safely sandboxed without forcing the same restrictions upon a landing page.
> - allow-presentation: Allows embedders to have control over whether an iframe can start a presentation session.
> - allow-same-origin: Allows the content to be treated as being from its normal origin. If this keyword is not used, the embedded content is treated as being from a unique origin.
> - allow-scripts: Allows the embedded browsing context to run scripts (but not create pop-up windows). If this keyword is not used, this operation is not allowed.
> - **allow-top-navigation**: Allows the embedded browsing context to navigate (load) content to the top-level browsing context. If this keyword is not used, this operation is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation @mplungjan! I was using this menu before in Wix platform (in an html snippet frame) and it worked perfectly, but I guess they change their framework...which really sucks in that aspect.

Answer (score 0):

We use target `_top` for `iframe`, If you are using `iframe` and want all click open in parent tab then you can use `_top` otherwise no need to use it

Comment: Thanks Super User..I'm not using iframe. I'm using it as a code snippet for a template website.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the links on the same tab then no need to add any target.....It will automatically open the links on the same tab (the default target value is "_self")

Comment: Thanks Srijan. It seem to make the nav bars disappear altogether...does it even make sense?